# Equivalent Definitions of Subharmonic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I want to prove the following are equivalent.

(a) For any $p \in U$ and $r>0$ with $\overline{D(p, r )} \subseteq U$,

if $h$ is harmonic on a neighborhood of $\overline{D(p, r)}$ satisfying $f \le h $ on $\partial D(p, r)$, then $f \le h$ on $D(p, r)$.

(b) For any $p \in U$ and $r>0$ s.t. $\overline{D(p, r )} \subseteq U$,

if $h$ is continuous on $\overline{D(p, r)}$ and harmonic on $D(p, r)$,satisfying $f \le h $ on $\partial D(p, r)$, then $f \le h$ on $D(p, r)$.

(a) $\Leftarrow $ (b) is obvious.

But I don't know how to prove the converse. The author says that I should use a 'limiting argument', but I'm not sure what 'limiting argument' refers to.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what is $f$ so I assume it is a continuous function on $U$.

For sake of simplicity, let assume that $r = 1$.
If $h$ is harmonic on $D(p, 1)$ then for any $t \in (0, 1)$, the function $h$ is harmonic on a neighbourhood of $\overline{D(p, t)}$. Since $h$ and $f$ are continuous on the compact set $\overline{D(p, 1)}$, then there are uniformly continuous on it. Thus, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $t_{\varepsilon} \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$ \forall t \in (t_{\varepsilon}, 1),\ \forall z \in \partial D(p, 1),\ |h(tz)-h(z)| \leqslant \varepsilon\ \mbox{ and }\ |f(tz)-f(z)| \leqslant \varepsilon. $$
In particular, we have $f - 2\varepsilon \leqslant h$ on $\partial D(p, t)$ for any $t \in (t_{\varepsilon}, 1)$. According to (a), we got $f-2\varepsilon \leqslant h$ on $D(p, t)$ for all $t \in (t_{\varepsilon}, 1)$. Thus $f-2\varepsilon \leqslant h$ on $D(p, 1)$. Let $\varepsilon$ tends towards zero to conclude.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that $f$ is continuous on $U$. Thanks for your help. Uniform continuity allowed us to take a slightly smaller disk to use (a)!